# Amazon Alexa Account Linking Throws Session Timeout on redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm using Amazon Security Profiles (LWA) for a new Alexa skill and following this tutorial: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3CX1ETRZZ2NPC/alexa-account-linking-5-steps-to-seamlessly-link-your-alexa-skill-with-login-with-amazon

Everything seems to work well. It redirects me to the Amazon login and shows me the scope to grant access.  I click allow and rather than seeing the "Your xyz Skill was successfully linked" message I see an error "Your session has timed out" with information to return to my app and log in again to continue using Login with Amazon.  I expected it to go back to the Alexa app and say I was good. I have two factor enabled for my Amazon account so I thought maybe that contributed to the timeout but I asked it to not prompt me again for this device and tried again and see the same timeout error message.

[image: Screen shot of error returned]

Comment: fyi, i added a quick video of what I see on my end: http://www.screencast.com/t/mM8Tq43NDz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have identified an issue preventing Account Linking preventing to succeed when using Login With Amazon *and* the Android Alexa App.

Account linking succeed from a desktop browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) or the iOS App.

Workaround is to whitelist “na.account.amazon.com” domain in Alexa developer portal.

We will update the system to add this for you by default.  I will let you know when available.

[UPDATE Jan 20]
Fix is now live and this problem seems to be solved

Comment: The problem seems to persist. Still having the same issues with the android app. Everything perfect when doing via desktop browser or ios device. Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get this to work on my Android device w/ firefox as default browser -

- Open firefox, go to amazon.com and log in
- From Alexa app - find my skill- link account.. it launched firefox.. then I agreed.. and it linked.

Seems like there's a loss of something between Alexa app and Firefox so the auth breaks.

Comment: I had the exact same problem as Ideluca.  I used firefox without logging into amazon.com in firefox, and it didn't work.  But once I followed both bullet points in your answer, it worked.  Thanks Steve.

Comment: I don't think all end users should have to use Firefox. But maybe that's the problem? My default mobile browser is chrome. I'll alert the Amazon team looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem here. I also have 2-step authentification on. Alexa will jump to Chrome, and stuck with this error.

I use a workaround by going to alexa.amazon.com to enable the skills and have no problems. However, on my Android phones, exactly the same problem appears.

Comment: I feel like this could have been a comment on the main question.